# Shrinkable menu in android

Tags: android, menu

I want to achieve a shrinkable menu in android. Couldn't find anything so far mainly because I have no idea how to describe it. Basically I want something that looks like this:
[image: state 1]

and goes like this when you click on the dots (works vice-versa):

[image: state 2]

So what should I even use in order to achieve that? Thanks in advance!